# How to show dropdown links in a particular order?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I want to show the drop-down links in a particular order. Right now the order is -

- Link 1
- Link 3
- Link 2

HTML Code -

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
         <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
       </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript Code -

```
if (role == "admin") {
  $(".dropdown-menu").append('<li>'+
  '<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>'+
   '</li>');
}
```

Can anyone tell me how can I show the links in the following order?

- Link 1
- Link 2
- Link 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (role == "admin") {
  $(".dropdown-menu :first").after('<li>'+
  '<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>'+
   '</li>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the `textContent` of the `a` tag after append and sort it out using `textContents.sort()` and then iterate the sorted `textContents` and update the anchor tag values back.

```js
const role = 'admin';

if (role == "admin") {
  $(".dropdown-menu").append('<li>'+
  '<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>'+
   '</li>');
}

  const anchors = $(".dropdown-menu").children('li').children('a');

  // extract the text
  const textContents = anchors.get().map((item) => item.textContent);

  // sort the text
  textContents.sort();

  // show reordered texts back into the original elements
  textContents.forEach((value, index) => {
    anchors[index].textContent = value;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
         <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
       </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```